# Diagnose crashes of dotnet core applications running in kubernetes (via Application Insights?)

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-insights, crash-reports, crash-dumps, azure-aks

we are just moving from Azure worker roles to Azure AKS. We are using Application Insights for monitoring our cloud services.

So far it was like this: If a worker role crashed (e.g. StackOverflow, OutOfMemory ...), a crash dump was generated, a log entry was generated and we were informed by email.

If a pods crashes in Kubernetes, it will automatically restart. However, we lack alerting options and analysis information such as crash dumps.

We are using [ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Kubernetes/), but this doesn't seem to offer such functionality.

What options are there to be informed about crashes and to receive diagnostic information?

Comment: Have you tried Container Insights? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/insights/container-insights-overview

Answer (score 0):

the best practices for core-dump management is to have those dumps shipped externally to a core dump server or external storage.

On easy way to achieve this would be to change the path where core-dumps are generated under and after that you can setup a mount point to have that path to be a HostPath (local volatile disk maybe ? /mnt)

```
/mnt$ ll
total 28
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Mar 24 19:24 ./
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root  4096 Apr  8 06:16 ../
-r--r--r--  1 root root   639 Mar 24 19:24 DATALOSS_WARNING_README.txt
drwx------  2 root root 16384 Mar 24 19:24 lost+found/
```

```
$> mkdir -p /mnt/cores
$> chmod a+rwx /mnt/cores
$> echo “/mnt/cores/core.%e.%p.%h.%t” > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

You could then write a daemonset Process that would mount the same folder and trigger emails when a new file is generated under /mnt/cores.

What can also centralized the core-dumps under a single Azure File, by leveraging the PVC and PV of type Azure File.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume

This would have each process create their dump file to a network storage. You can then look at the container of the Azure File (storage Account) in a programatic way to detect new files. Or setup alert when there is storage usage change (it tells you you have new data). This should be doable with the standard Azure Monitor feature for Storage Account..

I found an article that has the same idea more or less, but its on GCP, it should be quite similar.

https://medium.com/faun/handling-core-dumps-in-kubernetes-clusters-in-gcp-b1b2a54c25dc